# Annotate or add external data to XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

Having XML like this:

```
<interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../schema.xsd">
  <struct name="Owner" type="Person" />
  <variable name="Timestamp" />
</interface>
```

I want to add additional attributes to some elements, which only some XML documents will use, and which is targeted to specific parties interested in this information. For example, having some component which is able to display/present the XML file I would add:

Having XML like this:

```
<interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../schema.xsd">
  <struct name="Owner" type="Person" display:layout="vertical" />
  <variable name="Timestamp" display:hidden="true" />
</interface>
```

I don't want to change my XSD, because this additional information is some software module specific thing and doesn't apply to all documents.

If possible, I would like to have other XSD files, which can validate this new information.

How can I achieve this?

I'm reading about namespaces, XSD and extending types, but I'm afraid it only allows to extend types, so I would not be able to specify multiple annotations (display:, storage:...)

**Update:**

- I can modify existing schema - this is no problem. But the key point is, it shouldn't know anyhing about `display:`, `storage:` etc., because of:

  - Only some documents will make use of additional attributes (like display).
  - These new attributes might be added in future, when the main schema is fixed. Imagine a developer creating a new piece of software which works with these XML files and requesting additional information. They would agree somehow with a person who is creating a document and include this additional information there, without modifying rest of the system and the main XSD.
- XML files are created by hand. Actually the main reason to have XSD is to help with editing, having errors underline immediately, keyword completion etc.
- A perfect solution would be:

  - to be able to just add some other namespace (`xmlns:display=xxx`) and suddenly you have a bunch of new attributes available while editing the document,
  - ability to add multiple of them (`xmlns:display=xxx xmlns:storage=yyy` and whatever is needed and becomes defined in future)

Execuse me if the description wasn't clear from the beginning.

Comment: The only way to get this to work without touching the existing schema would be to create a custom schema containing the new namespaces and types and import the existing schema.

Comment: Check [xsd:include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256198(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to see the existing schema, it's difficult to give a definite answer to your question.  But some simple cases can be described:

1. The existing schema has lax attribute wildcards on the elements you care about, so that (for example) `display:layout` is accepted on `struct` and `display:hidden` on `variable`, and you can live without validation of the extension attributes.

In this case, nothing needs to be done.  Use your extension attributes in peace with the existing schema.

2. The existing schema has attribute wildcards on the elements you care about, so that (for example) `display:layout` is accepted on `struct` and `display:hidden` on `variable`, and either you wish to have the validator check the syntactic correctness of the extension attributes, or the wildcards in question are strict.

In this case, you need to write schema documents for the namespaces used by your extension attributes, and ensure that they are loaded, together with the existing schema, at validation time.  For the first, you might have a schema document something like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="..."
            xmlns:display="http://example.com/nss/display"
            targetNamespace="http://example.com/nss/display"
            >
  <xsd:attribute name="layout" type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:attribute name="hidden" type="xsd:boolean"/>

</
```

To ensure that the schema documents for the additional namespaces are loaded, check the API or CLI of your validator.  In the worst case you'll need to write a single 'driver' document that does nothing but load the appropriate set of schema documents.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="..."  
            ...
            >
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="schema.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com/nss/display"
    schemaLocation="display.xsd"/>
  ...
</
```

3. The existing schema does not have built-in extension points but does use top-level (named) types for the elements you care about and does not forbid extension of those top-level types.

For this case, you need to write a schema document which includes the existing one and extends the appropriate types with the attributes you want to use.

4. The existing schema does not have built-in extension points; it uses top-level (named) types for the elements you care about but forbids extension of those top-level types.

The schema author has taken steps to prevent your doing what you want to do while using the original schema document.

Copy the existing schema, change the types in question to allow or require the attributes you want to add, and use the original schema when you wish to validate against it, and use your modified schema when you wish to validate against that.  When the original schema changes, you will need to mirror the changes in your copied schema in order to preserve the desired relation between the original schema and your local version.

5. The original schema uses local type definitions for the elements in question.

Here, too, the schema author has attempted to prevent the kind of extension you wish to perform; your solution is again to copy the schema document and modify your copy.

> I'm reading about namespaces, XSD and extending types, but I'm afraid it only allows to extend types, so I would be able to specify multiple annotations (display:, storage:...)

The only modifications you have mentioned are extensions.  You are quite correct that type extension only allows extension.  To restrict a type, you must use type restriction.  Both extension and restriction can be performed across schema-document boundaries, if allowed by the original schema.

Comment: Than you for a very detailed answer. I think I didn't make everything clear, so I updated the question. The key point is, I can modify the main schema, but don't want to put additional attributes there. Which case would apply then?

Comment: The case you choose will apply, given that you can edit the main schema as you wish.  From your revised description, it sounds as if case 2 would work well:  add strict attribute wildcards to the relevant types.  When you load the additional schemas for the display and storage namespaces, the attributes you define will be valid; when you don't load the additional schemas, they'll be invalid.

Comment: Great, I think I got it working. I added `<xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" />` to the main schema, defined `display` XSD and I can add additional namespace to XML and use them on elements that allow for that. Two more questions I have, first in this comment: 1) What is the point of this line in your XSD in case 2 `xmlns:display="http://example.com/nss/display"`? (I removed it).

Comment: Question 2: Now I can add any attribute from `display` to any element that accept wildcard attributes, but have no control over which element can accept which attribute. I think I could leave with that if nothing better is possible, but is anything better possible? As I wrote I cannot reference `display` in the main XSD, but I could reference main XSD in `display`.

Comment: @Arek asks what the point in case 2 of the namespace declaration for prefix `display`.  Answer:  habit.  Many schema documents with target namespace N will want to refer to some components (e.g. types) with names in N; I routinely declare a prefix for the target namespace to make that possible.

Comment: @Arek asks how to restrict the choice of extension attributes on elements in the main schema.  Answer:  define a more restrictive type, using either an alternative schema document, or xsd:redefine, or xsd:override (in 1.1).